# Solve the following function with the independent variables given below

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, substitution

Given: $f(x) = \frac{4}{\sqrt{x-4}}$

Solve: $\frac{f(x) - f(20)}{x-20}$

My solution:  $\frac{(4x-80)\sqrt{x-4} - (x-4)(x-20)}{x-4}$

However, it says I am incorrect. Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: How did you solve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's differentiation of $f(x)$ because $\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}$.
We have $f(x)=\frac{4}{\sqrt{x-4}}$ 
$$\frac{df}{dx}=-\frac{2}{(x-4)\sqrt{(x-4)}}$$
put $x=20$ and get the answer.

Comment: When I placed (-1/32) after substituting x=20, the answer is incorrect.

Comment: What is the answer?

Comment: I am not sure. According to his derivation, I substituted x = 20 and I get (-1/32). But the computer is telling me that is incorrect. Please help. I am very bad at math

Comment: So you don't know the answer?Do you know any thing about the answer? any intuition you have?

Comment: This answer is correct. Why is it wrong jackson blackson?

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{f(x) - f(20)}{x-20}=\frac{\frac{4}{\sqrt{x-4}} - \frac{4}{\sqrt{20-4}}}{x-20}=\frac{\frac{4}{\sqrt{x-4}} - 1}{x-20}=\frac{\frac{4-\sqrt{x-4}}{\sqrt{x-4}}}{x-20}=\frac{4-\sqrt{x-4}}{(x-20)\sqrt{x-4}}$$

Comment: this is incorrect

Comment: @jacksonblackson you asked for $\frac{f(x) - f(20)}{x-20}$, I can't see any differentiation here...

Comment: @jacksonblackson  The question requests that you evaluate the difference quotient $$\frac{f(x) - f(20)}{x - 20}$$ This is correct.  The derivative at $x = 20$ is $$\lim_{x \to 20} \frac{f(x) - f(20)}{x - 20}$$ There is no limit in this problem.